# Switching input voltage, with two 3,3V inputs

Tags: power-supply, switches, 3.3v

I'm designing a circuit that can get its power from either a battery or a usb. The regulating of the battery and usb voltages is already done, and is regulated down to 3,3V.
If both supplies is connected at once, I don't want them both to supply. If both are connected, I only want the USB to power the circuit. If only the USB is connected, only the USB should power the circuit, and if only the battery is connected that should supply the circuit. How can I do this with ex. the use of MOSFETS or diodes? Thanks in advance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK7UKV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvaPSO.png)</sup>

Comment: What regulator are you using? That makes a difference. And what do you mean 'with ex the use of MOSFETS and diodes'? Do you mean using them for example? Or excluding using them?

Comment: I'm using two regulators, the battery uses a buck regulator with output: 3,3V 1A, and the USB uses a linear regulator with an output of 3,3V 500mA. I ment an example circuit or something similar, not exluding anything :)

Comment: @MCG I believe OP meant more along the lines of "How can I do this? Would something like diodes or MOSFETs be suitable for this?"

Comment: @OleHalvor my schematic is fixed now

Comment: @MCG I think the usb regulator needs to be connected to the input of the regulator to be enabled. It cannot enable it self if it never gets enabled in the first place?

Comment: Any suggestions on the diode spesifications? They need to be as small as possible in physical size.

Comment: To be enabled, the enable pin, or INH in your regulators instance, needs to be grounded. It needs to be low to be operational. When it gets a high signal from the other regulator, it is disabled. So the configuration I have is correct. It needs to be low to be operational, and pulled high to disable it. And you could use a BAT54J which has a low Vf and a small package. Just google low Vf Schottky diodes and find one with a package that suits your needs

Comment: But the output of U1 will enable U2 in your schematic? and U2 needs to have a signal to the enable pin in order to work, and it can't get that from itself that way I think

Comment: @OleHalvor yeah, sorry, I rushed it earlier when I got to the computer! I'll edit it again later once I have managed to get back to the computer. My phone doesn't let me do it!

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do this.

Personally, I think the easiest way is to get regulators that have a shutdown pin. With the battery input, you can have a pull-up resistor on the SHUTDOWN pin of the regulator. Have an N-channel MOSFET there aswell. When the USB is active, it toggles the MOSFET and pulls the shutdown pin low, which will effectively disable that regulator, then you can use the USB power.

Here is a *very* simplified version of this. It has all the information you need, but will still need a bit of work to make it applicable for your needs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9QXxG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT**

If you have a regulator with and active *high* disable pin, (as the example by OP) the above schematic could be edited as follows:

**EDIT 2**

Schematic fixed

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fITHZy.png)</sup>

Comment: This looks like the most reasonable way to go, since the application is a flight controller, and the pcb have limited space for components. My linear regulator has a shutdown pin, but I don't know for the buck regulator. Here is the datasheet for the buck regulator, maybe you can identify if it has a shutdown pin faster than me. http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l5970d.pdf

Comment: @OleHalvor Pin 3 (INH) disables the device when high. There is an internal pull-up on this pin.

Comment: As already pointed out, pin 3 controls the disabling of the device. It is, however, different to my example, as this one is disabled when the input is high. This makes it slightly easier, as you can replace the MOSFET for a pull down resistor. Then when the other regulator is active, it can toggle the pin high to disable it.

Comment: This is probably the cheapest and easiest solution!

Comment: Thanks, if this is my linear regulator, MIC5219-3.3BM5 https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/mic5219-1082354.pdf how would the schematic then look with a pull down resistor?

Comment: The only change would be to take my schematic, and remove the NMOSFET and pull-up resistor from the battery regulator, then have a pull-down in place of the MOSFET - See the edit to the answer @OleHalvor

Comment: Where's the switching happen? The state of the shutdown pins is the same no matter which regulator is on or if both are on.

Comment: @Samuel oh yeah..... whoops, I missed that bit! I meant the output from the bottom regulator to to post diode! Not at a computer atm so can't change it but that was a silly mistake! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: MCG and @Samuel , would the edited schematic on top be correct?

Comment: @OleHalvor almost, just tie the shdn pin from the top regulator to OUT on the bottom. I'll edit mine when I get back to my computer and remember to do it! Lol

Comment: @Samuel fixed the schematic now. Thanks for making me aware of that!

Comment: @OleHalvor It's still not right. The problem is that no matter which supply is active, both the regulators will have their shutdown pins pulled high. The Bat regulator shutdown pin should be tied to the output net of the USB regulator (when it's isolated from the load net). The USB shutdown pin can be disconnected.

Comment: @Samuel Yeah, another oversight. I'll get to it when I'm at a computer again and not rush it this time!

Comment: @OleHalvor There, forgot to add in the diode. Now when BAT is active, the SHDN pin is still low, meaning it is working, the diode blocks the output of that regulator switching itself off. When the USB comes on, the USB regulator is enabled, and switches off the Bat regulator. Apologies again for rushing it before!

Comment: Nice. Though I don't think that D1 is required. And the first schematic is still wrong.

Comment: Oh ffs! I didn't even look at that one! Haha. I'll sort it out another time! Lol

Answer (score 4):

The LTC4236 works below 3.3 volts so maybe consider this as an idea: -

[image]

There are two supply options on the left and the chip decides which one is to supply the load and it uses MOSFETs as a power OR gate. This type of circuit avoids the diode voltage drop in one or both power lines. The LTC4412 is more suited to supply voltages that are unregulated or different and will require a post regulator to convert to 3.3 volts.

I'm not recommending it verbatim but just suggesting that there are devices that can do this job and, if you are confident you can mastermind a version of this in discrete components.

Answer (score 3):

In the past I have used the LTC4412 for these kind of dual power supply designs.

It is a specially design powerpath controller which automatically switches inputs.

> The  system  designer  will  find  the  LTC4412  useful  in  a 
>   variety of cost and space sensitive power control applica
>   tions that include low loss diode OR’ing, fully automatic 
>   switchover from a 
>   primary to an auxiliary source of power, 
>   microcontroller controlled switchover from a primary to 
>   an auxiliary source of power, load sharing between two 
>   or more batteries, charging of multiple batteries from a 
>   single charger and high side power switching.

[Datasheet 4412](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J5VO.png)
[image: Example Design]

Comment: Both supply voltages are already pre-regulated to 3.3 volts and the LTC4412 makes it less attractive as a candidate in that respect. The LTC4412 would need a post regulator for this to work given that both supplies are already 3.3 volts.

Answer (score 1):

In response to answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/369665/186464:

It seems that with the battery only connected, it's output would be driving the shutdown pin anyways. This would cause it to attempt to turn itself off whenever it's on.

A possible fix is to have the Shut Down pin driven from the input of the USB regulator, though this may have issues with power interruption if the regulator takes time to get to full voltage.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is how the shcematic should look like with my regulators.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fygFen.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @Samuel this will work right?